# How do I get EGL and GL headers into yocto image?

Tags: yocto

I have a yocto image and now need to build a project from source on it. (not while building the image... although that might work, I thought it would be harder? the goal is to repro an issue, I only have build instructions, not a yocto recipe)

I've added:

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " git make clang pkgconfig libdrm-dev libgl-mesa-dev libegl-mesa-dev mesa-dev"
```

when I git clone, then make the project I get:

```
fatal error: 'GLES2/gl2.h' file not found
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
```

I figure I'm missing some *-dev that needs to be added to the image?
What do I need to add to get <s>egl</s> GL2 headers onto the image to build a C project?